# Angular Hybrid, how to load templateUrl's

Tags: angularjs, angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server, hybrid

I have an AngularJS/Angular hybrid build. For templateUrl's I'm using ngtemplate-loader for AngularJS and angular2-template-loader for Angular. The issue I'm having is loading the right templates depending on the Angular version. I can differentiate the html by naming convention. AngularJS files are fileName.html, whereas Angular files are fileName.component.html.

For ngtemplate-loader I have:

```
{
    test: /\.(html)$/,
    exclude: [/\.(^(?!.*\.component\.html).*.html$)/],
    use: [{
        loader: 'ngtemplate-loader',
        options: {
            prefix: '/',
            relativeTo: path.resolve(__dirname, './path/to/templates')
        }
    }, {
        loader: 'html-loader'
    }],
}
```

For angular2-template-loader I have:

```
{
    test: /\.ts$/,
    exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
    loaders: [ 'ts-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
}
```

How can I only touch templateUrl when it matches `.component.html`

I've tried using this expression without luck.

```
/\.(component\.html)$/
```

Comment: If you give some examples of what you want included & excluded I can help you will your regex

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get this working exactly how I wanted but I did find a useable workaround, I had to use require with template instead of the templateUrl property.

For the angularJS templates my regex was off a bit.

```
{
    test: /^(?!.*\.component\.html).*.html$/,
    use: [{
        loader: 'ngtemplate-loader',
        options: {
            prefix: '/',
            relativeTo: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'path/to/templates')
        }
    }, {
        loader: 'html-loader'
    }],
}
```

Then use ts and html loader as shown below.

```
{
    test: /\.ts$/,
    exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules'),
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'ts-loader'
        },
    ]
},
{
    /**
     * This loads all Angular templates. Angular templates must be called
     * {FileName}.component.html
     */
    test: /\.(component\.html)$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'html-loader'
        }
    ]
}
```

Now in you component you can load the template.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'template-component',
    template: require('./template-component.html')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use webpack look at this repository https://github.com/Zadvornyi/angular-hybrid-webpack

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ahw-accounts',
    styles: [require('./ahw-accounts.component.scss').toString()],
    templateUrl: './ahw-accounts.component.html'
})
```